# FFMpeg Stream specifier no match

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to combine 2 to n videos with various transitions with an audio from mp3 above them (last second is faded).

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -t 10 -i C:\Users\User\source\repos\tryRunFFmpeg\2_snow.mp4  
       -ss 5 -t 10 -i C:\Users\User\source\repos\tryRunFFmpeg\3_sun.mp4 
       -i C:\Users\User\source\repos\tryRunFFmpeg\outaudio.mp3
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts =PTS-STARTPTS[va0];[1:V]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=9.5:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[va1];[2:a]fade=t=out:st=9.5:d=0.5[aa];[va0][va1]overlay[outv]"
 -map aa -c:a copy  -map [outv] -crf 10 -b:V 10M -shortest C:\Users\User\source\repos\tryRunFFmpeg\testAgaint.mp4
```

and I get this error

```
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v]setpts =PTS-STARTPTS[va0];[1:V]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=9.5:d=0.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[va1];[2:a]fade=t=out:st=9.5:d=0.5[aa];[va0][va1]overlay[outv] matches no streams.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several minor problems with your command:

> `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description ... matches no streams.`

Change `[2:a]fade` to `[2:a]afade`. fade filter is for video. afade filter is for audio.

> `Filter afade has an unconnected output`

Change `-map aa` to `-map [aa]`.

> `Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.`

Remove `-c:a copy`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in `[2:a]fade=t=out:st=9.5:d=0.5[aa]` you probably meant to use `afade` audio fade filter instead of video fade filter `fade`.

Try this `[2:a]afade=t=out:st=9.5:d=0.5[aa]`.